# Maximal Substring Construction

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence, subsequence, restricted-time

In this challenge, you are passed two things:

1. A string length, `N`
2. A list of strings, `L`, each with an assigned point value.  Any string that is not passed in has a point value of 0

You need to construct a string of length `N` such that the sum of all substring points is as large as possible.

For example:

```
5 [("ABC", 3), ("DEF", 4), ("CDG", 2)]
```

should output

```
ABCDG
```

Because the two substrings with points (`ABC` and `CDG`) have a total of 5 points, and no other possible construction can give 5 or more points.

Substrings can be used multiple times in a string, and can overlap.  You can assume that the points will always be positive, the substring lengths will be between 1 to `N` characters longs, and that `N > 0`.  If multiple constructions are maximal, print any one of them.

Your program must run in a reasonable amount of time (no more than a minute for each of the examples):

```
1 [("A", 7), ("B", 4), ("C", 100)]     => C
2 [("A", 2), ("B", 3), ("AB", 2)]      => AB
2 [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("CD", 3)]      => BB
2 [("AD", 1), ("B", 2), ("ZB", 3)]     => ZB
3 [("AB", 2), ("BC", 1), ("CA", 3)]    => CAB
3 [("ABC", 4), ("DEF", 4), ("E", 1)]   => DEF
4 [("A", 1), ("BAB", 2), ("ABCD", 3)]  => AAAA or ABAB or BABA or ABCD
5 [("A", 1), ("BAB", 2), ("ABCD", 3)]  => BABCD or BABAB
5 [("ABC", 3), ("DEF", 4), ("CDG", 2)] => ABCDG
5 [("AB", 10), ("BC", 2), ("CA", 2)]   => ABCAB
6 [("AB", 10), ("BC", 2), ("CA", 2)]   => ABABAB
8 [("AA", 3), ("BA", 5)]               => BAAAAAAA
10 [("ABCDE", 19), ("ACEBD",  18), ("ABEDC", 17), ("BCEDA", 16), ("EBDAC", 15), ("BACD", 14), ("CADB", 13), ("ABDC", 12), ("CABD", 11), ("EBDC", 10), ("ACE", 9), ("CBA", 8), ("AEC", 7), ("BE", 6), ("AE", 5), ("DC", 4), ("BA", 3), ("A", 2), ("D", 1)]
=> ACEBDACEBD
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so prepare your shortest answer in your favorite language!

Comment: Do we have to use your exact input format or can we use any convenient input format for our language?

Comment: @flawr any convenient method of input is fine (dictionary, stdin, function params)

Comment: The `DEF` tuple missing a comma

Comment: I have a perfectly nice solution, but it's too slow for the last test case.

Comment: @isaacg post it, I'll see if my time limit needs to change.

Comment: @NathanMerrill No, it's a pure brute-force solution. The time-limit is fine.

Comment: @isaacg yeah that was the purpose of my last test case.  I'm trying to get a smart solution, which I'm hoping exists.

Comment: @isaacg I have an elegant solution, sadly this comment is too small to contain it. (I don't, just wanted to cite Fermat.)

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 383 bytes:

```py
lambda t,s,k={}:max(f(s,'',t,0,k),key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
C=lambda l,a:(l[:len(a)]==a)+(0if''==l else C(l[1:],a))
def U(l,a,k):
 if(l,a)in k:return k[(l,a)]
 k[(l,a)]=C(l,a);return k[(l,a)]
def f(s,l,t,p,k):
 if(T:=len(l))==t:yield(l,sum(b*U(l,a,k)for a,b in s));return
 for a,b in s:
  for i in range(len(a)):
   if l[T-i:]==a[:i]and T<len(L:=(l[:T-i]+a))<=t:yield from f(s,L,t,p+b,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZPBjtsgEIbvfgqUS6ChkknWaUqXgw1OL3tML3V9IIrdWiFOZHulRFWfPQVscHazPWxPHuCbmf8f8OnS/TrWi9Wpua7Zj6uSh@1Ogg63eM9@/6EHeYYlbPF0ijsc4j3C@@LCBupMzxnJURbmAXd7CksKVUZVUUOJcsYkmsGwKqdTxhQoVFsArs8JzbFEKNgVJfgGdZIuTQNQlSZGVQ32tCm650YHmd3KAx8xbr9fXgOmltGqtNSTr7ehzGhRCDHW0UtVqJ3m2@cD3H5wnctjAyTeAt23Ra5wAG63dTG7rsyqkfXPAvYWTRugGwGVbT5W1DjOaJXLegc2jwZ5oswMRB/mM40/OhWgbI4HK/jJCJ5ttZDrqanqDq4hwSCDk3iCwSeEAZwkOnqwEdcRCUOU6@k5eu7puacXNooTu/k2TDzcp3Fh83JwT4s38O99m9vai54emYT7RB7/E@fenUjXPk5t6i0fYY8v7nAuvt55fXjt9UaariPuFEX/mfAOTdE4IxKOQ5qPQ3rJL9/Jr3o@9oISE0Yvr5WETrewY/7cO@RpYiwCshocp8Je4PAIeSrsaJb9/SQitqfR0MaOhwzOY2EVu2fY13GibRdCXBk@etMS9KKXw63yQUrKx5/BIMth23qzcx9fUTKaH38K4Z7T9S8)

Comment: You can remove the space at `0 if` for -1, and you can also create a constant for the four `len(l)` for another -11 (by replacing the first `if len(l)==t` with `if(x:=len(l))==t`). Also, I'm not entirely sure, but I think `k[(l,a)]=C(l,a);return k[(l,a)]` can simply be `return C(l,a)`, in which case the entire method `U` can be `U=lambda l,a,k:(l,a)in k and k[(l,a)]or C(l,a)` for another -29.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you, updated. I did preserve `U`, as the caching is necessary for the program to run in under a minute for each test case.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I hadn't looked closely at what the actual program was doing, but it makes sense that method `U` is used for the caching portion. :)

Comment: [362](https://tio.run/##TY@7TsQwEEX7fMVQxSZGyooGmZ0qEtWWoTIuHK0DVpyHHK@UCPHtYZxlV3Rz7zzumWmNX@Pw/DKF7Q0/Nm/65mwgill0@P0je7Owls0iz0UUpei46OyKf1OLXNRBc1XqrLp5XhjJvJLeDsxwjWh4wUrX5jmiB@tnCxX1D1ILw3l2ti28M1qi0zID16aaD2MEN0AnO0VSY7W7GQQbL4H83d13E5sntOm@X0tM2Z5zxChXZ/2ZoOZLz5rHW1I7BjCiSRkzf71ezeC/S7d27ZIKZvi07PpRSgHKAa/qJyfTg0o6/YD1MQ2cKF1J6ujC8OMdoA1jv7OeEmvREMO2/QI "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") (footer stripped to save space)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 503 Bytes

This isn't particularly golfed, nor is it particularly efficient; it's just a relatively condensed enumeration of feasible strings that are brute-forced.  I don't think it would be too hard to create an admissible heuristic to use with A*, which would probably be a bit quicker.  I didn't bother doing that, though, because this method solves all of the examples in about 47 seconds on my laptop.

```
import re
v=lambda l,s:sum([len([m.start() for m in re.finditer('(?=%s)'%u,s)])*v for u,v in l])
def m(n,l,e):
 if len(e)==n:
  yield e
 else:
  u=1
  for s,v in sorted(l,key=lambda j:j[1],reverse=True):
   for i in range(len(s)-1,0,-1):
    if len(e)+len(s)-i <= n and e.endswith(s[:i]):
     for r in m(n,l,e+s[i:]):
      u=0;yield r
   if len(e)+len(s)<=n:
    for r in m(n,l,e+s):
     u=0;yield r
  if u:
   yield e
def p(n,l):
 b,r=-1,0
 for s in m(n,l,''):
  a=v(l,s)
  if a>b:b,r=a,s
 return r
```

To test it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n, l in [
            (1, [("A", 7), ("B", 4), ("C", 100)]),     # => C
            (2, [("A", 2), ("B", 3), ("AB", 2)]),      # => AB
            (2, [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("CD", 3)]),      # => BB
            (2, [("AD", 1), ("B", 2), ("ZB", 3)]),     # => ZB
            (3, [("AB", 2), ("BC", 1), ("CA", 3)]),    # => CAB
            (3, [("ABC", 4), ("DEF", 4), ("E", 1)]),   # => DEF
            (4, [("A", 1), ("BAB", 2), ("ABCD", 3)]),  # => AAAA or ABAB or BABA or ABCD
            (5, [("A", 1), ("BAB", 2), ("ABCD", 3)]),  # => BABCD or BABAB
            (5, [("ABC", 3), ("DEF", 4), ("CDG", 2)]), # => ABCDG
            (5, [("AB", 10), ("BC", 2), ("CA", 2)]),   # => ABCAB
            (6, [("AB", 10), ("BC", 2), ("CA", 2)]),   # => ABABAB
            (8, [("AA", 3), ("BA", 5)]),               # => BAAAAAAA
            (10, [("ABCDE", 19), ("ACEBD",  18), ("ABEDC", 17), ("BCEDA", 16), ("EBDAC", 15), ("BACD", 14), ("CADB", 13), ("ABDC", 12), ("CABD", 11), ("EBDC", 10), ("ACE", 9), ("CBA", 8), ("AEC", 7), ("BE", 6), ("AE", 5), ("DC", 4), ("BA", 3), ("A", 2), ("D", 1)]) # => ACEBDACEBD
    ]:
        print p(n, l)
```

**Explanation**

The `v` function simply calculates the value of a given string by searching for all occurrences of the substrings in L.  The `m` function enumerates all strings of length `n` with prefix `e` that can be generated from the substrings in `l`.  `m` recursively calls itself; the first call should pass in `''` for `e`.  For example:

```
>>> for s in m(4, [("A", 1), ("BAB", 2), ("ABCD", 3)], ''):print s
ABCD
BABA
ABCD
ABAB
AAAA
```

The `p` function simply loops through all possible strings (as enumerated by `m`) and returns the one with highest value (as determined by `v`).

Note that the `m` function actually prioritizes the enumeration by sorting based on substrings' values.  This turns out to be unnecessary to ensure optimality, and it actually hinders efficiency a bit; I could save ~20 or so bytes by removing it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZTRbpswFIbveYqjTFVgdaOQtF3HSicw2V5gV0URIoqzugM3siFTnz61jw0kaXpRXxBjn//jnP/Y2b42Ty9itt/zevsiG5DM28VVWa/WJVRERaqt/bxiws/riWpK2fgBbF4k1MCFDp5suFjzhkl/7P@ML1QwvmiJCpbB1x2GtWRnAqtl4K3ZBmpfkIqwIPKAb8BgWRDHQr/CK2fVGpgHrFLMLLRxqJ8GoixE6fzY2q/IP/bapfgcPefhkki2Y1Kx@I9sEW51HHMsxV/mm0@p4CokU3IV2oghg0u3y@E@BgGl0HlMmFir/7x58lUe8aWTIFYarKvkUuU86nd1ztMfthDpnfnCvS31HKZDHBM0oMWNzh1j4tZoTPyKyNiU5FmXBt54jLgy3mm3VGBB5cMqMoqSKE93rmmlNmevN4pClDUrCohjGBVFXXJRFKMhUUGgMuzcFWmHHxLI/VEyIvAtIOCPUj27xhnVs3A61aeAYOgXiB@AHqtnvXrWq@c4S1Jc7MRWnaQfycNebkE0Q9KxPD0vz87oH9MjPcofT@RzKx9EKe1JNDnU29KTD/S0tyxb/OrnC2RZAOr15rH@@rT6g1Q09cABa54eoBuZ6Djzq3/cO82OwTefA6dmrSOmZ1FY4/xdjTT73XfZNVgvnSfgaRpsng02zw5d0oTTHG4/S3hfxp1FJH0VqZneDOerH84RO06uyrQzI8PmfreG0kVqHIXwzhm8yPAcuftEFxl24taeijRLcPfGpYHdCJ2dSYZFdjfIcro68Sth2GHoYIdOQb/YdChW5lJZ0OFem5Bbt4y1YzOHs5sO5gz3OXOH2DlLMX39QGOWUe/PVnLR4F8aVMH@DQ)